# Model of a language $L$ vs. model of a theory $T$ in $L$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

I am reading [Just/Weese](http://books.google.com/books/about/Discovering_Modern_Set_Theory_The_basics.html?id=x74azoKzb_MC&redir_esc=y) and they seem to use "model of a language $L$", for example, p. 90:

[image]

and, more disturbingly, p. 91:

[image]

Isn't this a "typo" (or perhaps sloppy writing)? If $L$ is any language and $\varphi$ any formula in $L$ then $\lnot \varphi$ is also a formula in $L$. Hence there cannot be a model of $L$.

But most likely I am missing something fundamental. So: where did I go wrong? Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

Perhaps this is related and the authors use theory and language as synonyms: on page 92

[image]

Well... what? Isn't ZFC the 9 or so axioms given for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)?

Comment: Note that the axiom *schema* of replacement is actually an infinite list of axioms. How cool is set theory now? We can write infinitely many axioms! POW!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just slightly sloppy terminology to avoid introducing nearly synonymous words.

- A model of a *(first-order) language* would be just a set together with appropriate interpretations of all constant, function and relation symbols.
- A model of a *theory* would then be a model of the language in which all the sentences/formulae of the theory are true.

You can argue that a language specifies its formulae, and therefore a model of a language should *morally* be a model of all formulae of that language, as per the second point, but then you have to find a way to bootstrap yourself to the second definition.

In practice this shouldn't cause too much difficulty, as whenever you come across *model* in Just-Weese (or elsewhere) it should be clear from context which meaning is intended.

(Sometimes *structure* or *interpretation* is used for models of the first type, reserving *model* for models of the second type.)

At times it's almost enough to make you wonder if the sloppiest expositions in mathematics come from the AMS's [03-XX](http://msc2010.org/mscwiki/index.php?title=03-XX) subject classification....

---

**Added due to edit.**

I'm almost certain that Just-Weese do not use *language* and *theory* as synonyms.  Consider the second paragraph of quoted text in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243104/8348).

And, no, ZFC does not consist of only nine axioms.  In particular the [Axiom Schema of Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (sometimes called *(Restricted) Comprehension*, or *Specification*) consists of an infinite list of axioms.  But I believe this comes up later in Chapter 7 of Just-Weese.

You might even see later (in Chapter 12) that there is no finite axiomatization of ZFC (assuming the consistency of ZFC).